# how can I solve the image uploading issue in laravel on shared hosting without ssh?

Tags: laravel, shared-hosting

[image][image][image]i uploaded my laravel project on a shared hosting platform everything is working fine except the image upload feature probably due to the storage:link command issue.is there any alternative for the same

[image]

Comment: You can create symlink (if you are using a linux host)

Comment: i am using hostinger for hosting my file

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the output error, it maybe permission issue and ... , but again you can use manual file upload to a folder in laravel like so :

```
if($request->hasFile('file_input_name')){
    $file = $request->file('image');
    $name = md5(time()) . '.' . $file->etClientOriginalExtension();
    $file->move(public_path('files'),$name);
}
```

before anything create a folder named **files** in public folder and set its permission to 755.
Good Luck.

Comment: heyy buddy thank you for reverting. i think the issue is because laravel has a file called public and hostinger i.e my hosting service has a file called public_html which i cannot delete or rename and i have to put all the files from my public folder in to the public_html folder in order to deploy the application.please help

Comment: @JeffrinJose did you uploaded all your laravel files in public_html ?

Comment: no i didnt i made an other file outside the pulic_html.and  i did the necessary changes in the index file

Comment: laravel looks for public in current directory you have to set the public path by yourself.you can also move all your files to public_html no big deal and then everything should work fine.otherwise the first method.

Comment: if i keep all my files in public_html then will the issue be solved?

Comment: @JeffrinJose %70 yes, I could say %100 when I could read any error or some outputs.

Comment: @JeffrinJose youn do not have any SSH access , if you had you could use terminal and ssh to create a symlink for your public folder.

Comment: i dont get any error message while uploading the file its just a blank screen that appears i have uploaded the photos above in the question

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTlZF.png this is the snip shot of thepage that i get after uploadng the image but in the localhost it was working perfectly

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDgmL.png this is how i have kept my file

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqzYt.png this is before selecting the image please ignore the icon

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/teMLY.png this is after selecting the image and then the blank page comes after clicking on save changes

Comment: i need a direct alternative for the php artisan storage:link  command

Answer (score 0):

it seems like a permission issue 
your last column in the second picture is for permission separated in 3 type 
owner-group-other  `w` for write `r` for reading `x` for executing 
you have to check your images folder permission to accept write permission

Comment: i did give all the permission and i also used symlink the photos are getting uploaded in my file manager  but can not be viewed by the users                          <div class="profile-avatar" style="width: 400px;height:500px; border-radius: 0%;background-image: url('@if(Auth::user()->avatar == "avatar.png") {{ url("/imgs/".Auth::user()->avatar) }} @else {{ url("/storage/avatar/".Auth::user()->avatar) }} @endif');"> this is how i used to view it on my local host

Comment: try to display image like this
<img src="{{ Storage::url("/storage/avatar/{Auth::user()->avatar}") }}" alt="{{ Auth::user()->avatar }}" />